# How to delete posts without featured images in wordpress via mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

How can posts without featured-images be removed via mysql in wordpress ?

I tried this code but it delete all posts which include featured-images also. I just want to remove posts only that without featured-images.

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE ID not in (select post_id as p from wp_postmeta where meta_key like "_wp_attached_file")
```

Comment: I also tried to find plugin for this task, but unable to find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that you are pulling back the 'post_id' for all sorts of things.

The meta_key value you want is "_thumbnail_id" which will have the parent post stored in post_id.

DELETE at your own peril, you might try a SELECT instead of DELETE first to make sure this does what you really want:

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE ID not in (select post_id as p from wp_postmeta where meta_key like "_thumbnail_id");
```

UPDATE:  Here is my validation test.

Created a new post (7161), then added a feature image.

```
mysql> select * from wp_postmeta where post_id IN(7161,7162);
+---------+---------+---------------+---------------------+
| meta_id | post_id | meta_key      | meta_value          |
+---------+---------+---------------+---------------------+
|   12533 |    7161 | _edit_lock    | 1512581739:1        |
|   12534 |    7161 | _edit_last    | 1                   |
|   12549 |    7161 | _thumbnail_id | 7115                |
|   12543 |    7161 | CODE1         |                     |
|   12544 |    7161 | _CODE1        | field_57e4293a9238c |
|   12545 |    7161 | CODE3         |                     |
|   12546 |    7161 | _CODE3        | field_57e4297c9238d |
|   12547 |    7161 | CODE2         |                     |
|   12548 |    7161 | _CODE2        | field_57e42ceb508ff |
```

Created a clone of the wp_posts table

```
create table wp_posts_test like wp_posts;
  Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

and loaded it with live data from wp_posts.

```
insert into wp_posts_test select * from wp_posts;
  Query OK, 6938 rows affected (0.30 sec)
```

Then ran my test query to delete anything without a featured image:

```
delete from wp_posts_test WHERE ID NOT IN (select post_id from wp_postmeta where meta_key="_thumbnail_id"); 
   Query OK, 6937 rows affected (0.37 sec)
```

Checked the table, and there is only one record, and it's the post I wanted to keep:

```
select * from wp_posts_test \G

*************************** 1. row ***************************
                   ID: 7161
          post_author: 1
            post_date: 2017-12-06 09:29:20
        post_date_gmt: 2017-12-06 17:29:20
         post_content: This is just a test post to see if the featured image OR the post is nuked using a mysql hack.   Standby for destruction. 
           post_title: Feature Image Test Post
        post_category: 0
         post_excerpt: 
          post_status: publish
       comment_status: open
          ping_status: open
        post_password: 
            post_name: feature-image-test-post
              to_ping: 
               pinged: 
        post_modified: 2017-12-06 09:35:18
    post_modified_gmt: 2017-12-06 17:35:18 
post_content_filtered: 
          post_parent: 0
                 guid: http://blog.daviddemartini.com/?p=7161
           menu_order: 0
            post_type: post
       post_mime_type: 
        comment_count: 0
```

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

It looks like it works perfectly fine to me, if you wanted to remove all the records from wp_posts that didn't have an association to a featured image.   Why it might not be working for you, is a mystery to me.

Comment: Hi thanks for help  sorry im out of town for some urgent work so dont update you. im back now and just test this code  this delete all thumbnail ( featured-images) from posts. can you please look into it . thanks again

Comment: When I tested this, it located all the posts that did not have a meta record of the thumbnail type (which indicates there is an associated featured image).  Wasn't that the goal, or is there another objective?

Comment: I want that the posts which doesn't have a featured image, gets deleted. But with your code, the featured image itself gets removed from the posts which have it.

Comment: My test worked by creating a copy of wp_posts  as wp_posts_tests and running the query.  I had only one post with a featured image, after running the query, only that post ID was left in wp_posts.  If that's not working for you, then I'm not sure what the reason is, but it's working fine for me on the latest release of WordPress.

Comment: thanks for your time and help , i think problem is from my end, as im unable to use phpmyadmin at this time so i use wordpress plugin (SQL Executioner) and Results
Raw query: DELETE FROM avwp_posts WHERE ID not in (select post_id as p from avwp_postmeta where meta_key like "_thumbnail_id");
3449 rows affected , so i think i use plugin for this maybe the reason . thanks again ..

Comment: Hm, it might be removing the subquery as sort of sql injection security measure, that could explain the difference in what's happening.  :/

Answer (score 0):

DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE ID not in (select post_id as p from wp_postmeta where meta_key like "_thumbnail_id");
It just deleted all future images from posts.